# F# how to for loop from -1 to 1 or 1 to -1?

Tags: f#

I want something like j = 1 .. j = -1 and i = -1 .. i = 1, I know the Java/C# way of doing it, but not in F#.

```
   for j in 1 .. -1 do
    for i in -1 .. 1 do
      //all 9 combination.
```

Guidance please, thankyou.

Comment: Constant memory, as a sequence, using the order you requested in Mark's answer: `seq { for j in 1..-1..-1 do for i in -1..1 -> i, j }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Jaya's and Phillip Trelford's answers are good. If you want a sequence of all the combinations instead of an imperative loop, you can do this:

```
let combinations =
    [1 .. -1 .. -1]
    |> Seq.collect (fun i -> [-1 .. 1] |> Seq.map (fun j -> (i, j)))
```

This produces a sequence like this (when converted to a list):

```
[(1, -1); (1, 0); (1, 1); (0, -1); (0, 0); (0, 1); (-1, -1); (-1, 0); (-1, 1)]
```

---

If you want a different order, you can always sort the tuples, but it might be more efficient to generate the sequence differently. If, for example, you want this sequence:

```
(-1,1) (0,1) (1,1) (-1,0) (0,0) (1,0) (-1,-1) (0,-1) (1,-1)
```

you can simply switch `i` and `j` around:

```
let combinations =
    [1 .. -1 .. -1]
    |> Seq.collect (fun i -> [-1 .. 1] |> Seq.map (fun j -> (j, i)))
```

which produces this sequence (converted to a list for readability):

```
[(-1, 1); (0, 1); (1, 1); (-1, 0); (0, 0); (1, 0); (-1, -1); (0, -1); (1, -1)]
```

Comment: What if I want it this order ?(1,1) (0,1) (1,1) (-1,0) (0,0) (1,0) (-1,-1) (0,-1) (1,-1)

Answer (score 8):

When [looping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233236.aspx) down to a number you can use the downto keyword:

```
for j = 1 downto -1 do
  for i = -1 to 1 do
```

or you can use the [for in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233227.aspx) range syntax in @Jaya's answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
   for j in 1.. -1 .. -1 do
     for i in -1 .. 1 .. 1 do
        printf "%d , %d" i j
```

Comment: +1, but see [my anwer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22804151/126014) for a way to *produce* the combinations, instead of imperatively looping.

Comment: @MarkSeemann, Your answer is good.But the question is How to for loop rite?

Answer (score 1):

If you are really just counting -1, 0, 1, then it might be clearer to just write it out:

```
for j in [1; 0; -1] do
  for i in [-1; 0; 1] do
    printfn "%d,%d" i j
```